# How do I ensure serialized transactions, in EF6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We have an ASP.NET/MVC 4.5 website using Entity Framework 6, and we have an issue where multiple users are trying to create new incident records, and are conflicting because they're trying to use the same incident numbers.

The context is somewhat complicated.

We have an [Incident] record, that contains meta-data about an incident:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Incident] (
    [customerid] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [incidentnumber] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [currentrevisionnumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_IMincident] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [customerid] ASC,
        [incidentnumber] ASC
    )
)
```

But most of the data about the [Incident] is contained in the [IncidentContent] record:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncidentContent] (
[customerid] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[incidentnumber] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[revisionnumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
// assorted fields recording information about the incident.
CONSTRAINT [PK_IMincidentContent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [customerid] ASC,
    [incidentnumber] ASC,
    [revisionnumber] ASC
)
```

Note that [revisionnumber] is an IDENTITY field, but it is not, in and of itself, the primary key. Don't ask me why.

The purpose behind this design is maintain a complete history of how the data recorded about an incident evolves. Once written, an IncidentContent record never changes. On an update a new IncidentContent record is created, with a new [revisionnumber], and [Incident].[currentrevisionnumber] is set to the new [revisionnumber].

[customerid] is simple enough, it indicates which customer this data is for. We have multiple customers using this system.

[incidentnumber] is more complicated. It's a generated identifier, YYDDDNNN, where YY is the last two digits of the year, DDD is the number of the day within the year, and NNN is a sequence number, starting at 1 every day, for each customer.

To track that we have an [IncidentSequence] table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncidentSequence] (
    [customerid] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [sequence] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [lastupdatedtutc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [incidentPrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [customerid] ASC,
    [sequence] ASC
)
```

Then we have a stored procedure that uses that table to generate the next [incidentnumber]:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getNextIncidentNumber]

    @customerid NVARCHAR(32),
    @currentdate DATETIME,
    @incidentnumber NVARCHAR(12) OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE 

    @yr AS CHAR(2),
    @cnt AS TINYINT,
    @doy AS VARCHAR(3),
    @sequence AS VARCHAR(3),
    @cdate AS DATETIME,
    @ldate AS DATETIME;

    IF @customerid IS NULL 
      SET @customerid = 'SYSTEM';
    IF @currentdate IS NULL 
      SET @currentdate = GETUTCDATE();
    
    SET @yr = (YEAR( GETDATE() ) % 100 );
    SET @cdate = @currentdate;
    SET @doy = DATEDIFF(day,STR(YEAR(@cdate),4)+'0101',@cdate)+1;
    SET @doy = REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(@doy)) + @doy;


    /* Check to see if customer ID exists */
    SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM [IncidentSequence]
    WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;
    
    /*NEW CUSTOMER ID*/
    IF (@cnt = 0)
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO [IncidentSequence]([customerid], [sequence], [lastupdatedtutc])
       VALUES(@customerid, 0, @cdate);
    END
    /*NEW CUSTOMER ID*/

    /*DETERMINE IF WE NEED TO RESET THE SEQUENCE NUMBER*/
    SELECT @ldate = [lastupdatedtutc], @sequence = [sequence]
    FROM [IncidentSequence]
    WHERE customerid = @customerid;
    
    IF DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @cdate)) <> DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @ldate))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [IncidentSequence] 
        SET [sequence] = 1,
        [lastupdatedtutc] = @cdate
        WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN    
    
        /* UPDATE THE SEQUENCE */
        UPDATE [IncidentSequence] 
        SET [sequence] = [sequence] + 1,
        [lastupdatedtutc] = @cdate
        WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;
    END

    SELECT @sequence = [sequence]
    FROM [IncidentSequence]
    WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;

    SET @sequence = REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(@sequence)) + @sequence;

    SET @incidentnumber = @yr + @doy + @sequence;

    RETURN

END

GO
```

Finally, we have the C# code that tries to obtain a new [incidentnumber], write a new [IncidentContent], obtain the [revisionnumber] from the new [IncidentContent], and to write a new [Incident], setting its [currentrevisionnumber], in a single transaction, so that either both records are created and IncidentSequence is updated, or neither record is created and IncidentSequence is not updated.

```
public void InsertIncidentModel(Incident incident, IncidentContent incidentContent, 
    string customerid, DateTime? localDt)
{
    using (var db = new IncidentsDbContext())
    {
        using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var incidentnumberParameter = new ObjectParameter("incidentnumber", typeof(string));
                db.sp_getNextIncidentNumber(customerid, localDt, incidentnumberParameter);
                var incidentnumber = incidentnumberParameter.Value as string;

                incident.currentrevisionnumber = -1;
                incident.incidentnumber = incidentnumber;
                db.IMincidents.Add(incident);

                incidentContent.incidentnumber = incidentnumber;
                db.IMincidentContents.Add(incidentContent);
                db.SaveChanges();

                incident.currentrevisionnumber = incidentContent.revisionnumber;
                db.SaveChanges();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                this._logger.logException(ex, "Exception caught in transaction, rolling back");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Our problem is that when two users are creating incidents at the same time, they sometimes seem to end up with the same incident number, and that results in errors.

It's clear that the original author of this expected that wrapping this in a transaction would prevent this - that SQL's locking would block one transaction until the the other had completed. I'm not sure that is the case, in this situation.

How can two transactions, running this C# code, result in two different incidents with the same [incidentnumber]?

How can I fix this?

There are two places where we read from [IncidentSequence]:

```
/* Check to see if customer ID exists */
SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM [IncidentSequence]
WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;

...

/*DETERMINE IF WE NEED TO RESET THE SEQUENCE NUMBER*/
SELECT @ldate = [lastupdatedtutc], @sequence = [sequence] FROM [IncidentSequence]
WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;
```

I'm thinking that perhaps if we replaced them with one read, and checked if @ldate was NULL, to determine whether we needed to insert a record, and then added an UPDLOCK hint?

```
SELECT @ldate = [lastupdatedtutc], @sequence = [sequence]
FROM [IncidentSequence] WITH (UPDLOCK)
WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;
```

That should hold a lock on the [IncidentSequence] record until the end of the transaction.

Thoughts?

Would I need to set a different isolation level on the transaction?

```
using (var db = new IncidentsDbContext())
{
    using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
```

Comment: What _I_ would do is create UNIQUE indexes on the table. When they invariably complain about duplicates, rollback and try again.

Comment: Actually, that isn't true - I would do the schema differently (using IDENTITY). But that is a larger change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the table with a restrictive lock to properly serialize transactions. Typically, you do this on the first query of the transaction, but UPDLOCK alone is not enough here.  It also needs `holdlock`. eg

```
/* Check to see if customer ID exists */
SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM [IncidentSequence] with (updlock,holdlock)
WHERE [customerid] = @customerid;
```

This will read with a restrictive U lock, instead of using row versions or a permissive S lock.  And the `holdlock` will force a range lock even in the case that that are no current rows for that @customerid.

Also you might to add BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN to the stored procedure in case the client hasn't started a transaction, or enforce it with an error, like

```
if @@trancount = 0 
 throw 60000, 'This procedure must be called with a tranaction', 1
```

And

> Would I need to set a different isolation level on the transaction?

No. No isolation level will cause readers to block readers.  SERIALIZABLE will "solve" the problem, but only by creating deadlocks to enforce the serialization of transactions, which is inconvenient.  But SERIALIZABLE + retry-on-deadlock would also be a solution.